# Finding timing out request in AWS ALB access logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, aws-application-load-balancer

My server gets a SIGABRT because of memory issue every now and then and I want to detect on which requests this issue happens specifically. I am guessing those requests should timeout on load balancer and ALB should send a specific status code to client. My questions are:

- What would be the status code sent to the client?
- In ALB Access logs, how can I search for the timing out request? I looked at here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html and searched for -1 in logs but did not get any result.

Comment: You can use `query with s3 select` as the logs are in s3 and exclude the known codes (200, 403, 503 etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep " \"-\" \"-\" \"-\""
```

seems to work. it looks like on timeout the target status code list becomes `-`